# python command not working, pointing to a virtualenv python?

Tags: python

I screwed up my local python. What can I do?

```
which python
/Users/jwan/application/env/bin/python
 11:54 AM   / 
$ python
bash: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

It looks like some virtualenv magic. What is happening? `deactivate` isn't found as a commmand either.

I basically want to run my tests using `python` instead of `python3`. How do I do this?

Comment: if you screwed up your python, reinstall it?

Comment: take a look at your environment variables and be sure no symbolic links exist

Comment: Whats the output of `echo $PATH` and `type -a python`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try change the PATH variable, and add the path where you installed your python. It'll work just fine.

Steps : (windows 8, 8.1, 10) :

> 1) Search 'environment' in the start menu. (These windows version just give amzing start menus I love them!)
>
> 2) Go to 'Environment Variables'.
>
> 3) Edit the 'Path' variable in the above white box.
>
> 4) Add your custom path and save.

Now try your command again. Hope it helps. (If not, tell me.)

Peace out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the **PATH** environment variable to the directory you want.

The terminal gets the first match it finds on PATH's directory to use the command, so making this should work.

On Bash, you can do this:

```
$ export PATH="<Python dir>:$PATH"
```

You can also create an alias for python3.

```
$ alias python=python3
```

You can add this to your `~/.bashrc` to make it *"permanent"*.

For more info about this, i suggest looking for this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/321000